# Why I cannot make the setSelectedIndex work?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, indexing, actionlistener

So I'm trying to make the buttons go through each of my tab panels and it works just fine. Now I have to make them repeat the running through the tabs every time one of the tabs reach the end. I made the "previous" button work, and it works, but I can't seem to get the right numeric expression to make the "next" button work. I've tried many different numeric expressions but this is what I have so far:

```
next = new JButton("next");
    next.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.getSelectedIndex()+1);
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.getSelectedIndex()-7);
                }
            });

    previous = new JButton("previous");
    previous.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                        tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.getSelectedIndex()-1);
                        tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabs.getSelectedIndex()+6);
                }
            });
```

and this is the Exception that gives me every time I try the next button:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -6, Tab count: 6
```

When I finally get it to work, it skips the last tab, so I really don't know what am I doing wrong, but I have a feeling is because of the numeric expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a cycle for edges cases.

Something like this.

```
next = new JButton("next");
    next.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int nextIndex = tabs.getSelectedIndex()+1;
                    tabs.setSelectedIndex( (nextIndex < tabs.getTabCount())?nextIndex:0 );                                                 
                }
            });

    previous = new JButton("previous");
    previous.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    int previousIndex = tabs.getSelectedIndex()-1;
                     tabs.setSelectedIndex((previousIndex < 0)?tabs.getTabCount()-1:previousIndex);                         
                }
            });
```

Comment: (nit pick) I'd probably have a single call to `tabs.setSelectedIndex` and modify the index value as required...but that's just me ;)

Comment: @nachokk Thank you, that really did it. So the if loop sets the current position of the Index, and else returns the position of the Index. Right?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's what I was trying to do, but it kept skipping the last tab, and I don't know why.

Comment: @MadProgrammer me too but well i think in this way is clear if he don't have too many skills yet

Comment: @nachokk As I said - nit pick ;) - It's certainly the correct answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer hehe im not native english speaker don't even know what is nit pick but i edited before you commented as you suggest hihi

Comment: @nachokk Are you referring to me as a he? I'm a she, but I don't blame you, most people don't recognize my nickname as a she LOL!

Comment: @Mandygir hehe sorry!! it's about statics haha was more probably that you were a man, actually also madprogrammer could be a woman xD

Comment: @nachokk That's okay, it was funny. XD